# curl, fopen & file_get_contents Randomly throw "The connection was reset" error in browser

Tags: php, curl, fopen, file-get-contents

I have tried the 3, `file_get_contents`, `curl` & `fopen`but the problem is I get the "The connection was reset" error randomly, i mean if it works for url A but fails with url B.

Any help would be appreciated.

Heres the code:

```
function readRemoteFile($url, $use = FOP) {
$url = urldecode($url);
switch ($use) {
    case FOP:

        $handle = fopen($url, 'r');
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $content.=fread($handle, 2048);
        }
        return $content;
        break;
    case FGC :

        if (!$handle = file_get_contents($url)) { 
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            while ($chunk = fread($handle, 2048)) {
                $content .= $chunk;
            }
            fclose($handle);
            return $content;
        }
        break;
    case CURL :
        $ch = curl_init(urldecode($url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        ob_start ();
        $c = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        ob_end_clean ();
        return trim($c);
        break;
}
```

}

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
case FGC :

    if (!$handle = file_get_contents($url)) { 
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        while ($chunk = fread($handle, 2048)) {
            $content .= $chunk;
        }
        fclose($handle);
        return $content;
    }
```

Is wrong. It should be:

```
case FGC :
  return file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Another thing i forgot to mention is that if i call the same function on the index page, it does fine,

Comment: after doing some debugging, I found that the browser 
displays the "The connection was reset" error after I call the 
`$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $feedUrls);`
where as the `$content` contains the html which is returned by the `readRemoteFile` function.
Does anyone one know why is it happening?

Regards,

Comment: @jey-keu preg_match_all is not in the source code you posted, so I have no idea.

Comment: Ok, heres what I was doing  
    //read page content (html) from $url  
    $content = readRemoteFile($url);  
    $pattern="some pattern";  
    $matches = array();  
    $result = preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);  
    if($result)  
    {  
        //I do stuff here  
    }  
I have read somewhere that `preg_match_all` fails if `$subject` (the 2nd parameter) contains a large string.
For now plz ignoring the `preg_match_all` part as i no longer need it, what I actually want to do is parse the html present in the `$content`.

Comment: Sorry, from the information you gave I can not diagnose the problem. Try opening a new question with the complete contents of your source code. Also, take a look in your logfiles - maybe php or your webserver is logging something.